# How to change the order of keys in gnome-keyring

Tags: ssh, gnome-keyring

I have 2 SSH keys in the gnome-keyring (let's name them AA and BB) and I have a lot of problems because I need to use the BB key(for example for a bitbucket server) and it automatically uses AA key instead. 
I modified ~/.ssh/config with different configurations with no success.
Also the seahorse gui does not have an option to do this.

Basically I want to use in all situations the AA first, and then the BB.
Is there a way to do this? thanks

Also I found another problem, if I remove AA key from bitbucket and I have locally AA and BB, then try to clone a repo, I get error, instead of trying with BB key...

Details:
I am using key AA for connecting via ssh to remote hosts,
I want to use key BB for bitbucket,
I have both keys in my ~/.ssh folder.

But when I try to clone the bitbucket repo, it says that I don't have rights(because key AA does not have rights, indeed).
When I delete the key AA, bitbucket works perfectly, but I still need key AA for remote ssh.

I modified my ssh config:

`Host gitserv
    Hostname remote.server.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    User remoteusername`

LE: I "fixed" this using a hack, by adding the AA key in .ssh/other_keys/ folder and using the above conf, because it seems that gnome-keyring only monitors .ssh folder. It's clearly a bug, I don't know where to address it.

Comment: Can you provide details on what kind of problems you're seeing? Are you using the command-line to ssh to remote hosts? What were the changes you made to ~/.ssh/config?

Comment: Ok Thomas, I added some details in my original post,thanks

Comment: And you're using gnome-keyring as your ssh agent, which should load both of these keys (see https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Ssh for details)? So what is the error that you're getting on the command-line?

Comment: I did not change the way gnome keyring works as ssh-agent, but I think it replaces it, because it's the default behaviour in xfce, AFAIK. The error I get on git clone is that AA does not have enough rights to clone that repo.

Comment: I have this problem and your answer in the original post helped me to solve it, thank you. Here's my related question on SO:https://stackoverflow.com/q/55665572/9779791 Any updates on how can we solve it without using hacky ways?